# Where to put .hs and .jhm for Java help file in NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-6.9

I am creating a Java help file. I don't know where to create `.hs` and `.jhm` files using Met Beans 6.9.1. If I create a program in `html`, it's saving as `.html`, but I don't know where to create `.hs` file.

Please suggest a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here a **maven** project might help. Maven provides a build infrastructure with library dependency management and "best practices", especially folder conventions. I searched an older (for 6.9) example and found http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/javahelp_in_a_mavenized_netbeans - the overhead is minimal.

Try it out as new project first.

https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/docs/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/javahelp/javahelp.html#JavaHelp-Conceptual-Overview-Components-Helpset
is a nice overview. The helpset would go in the main directory, and in it the location of the help map is specified; could also be the main directory.